# jquery validation range via database on laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, laravel, validation

I have three fields in a database

table name

> mail_messages

properties of the table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('mail_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('type');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->unsignedInteger('from_value')->default('0');
        $table->unsignedInteger('to_value')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

When entering a new data, I need to validate into the same type (1,2,3, etc) that the ranges of from_value and to_value are not intercepted among other messages of the same old type (stored in the database of data)

If I do not explain myself very well, I leave an explanatory image

[image: Explanation]

[image]

From that table, when I want to create a new "message", I need to check so that no new input intercepts its range, that is, inside the type variable (those COM01 are actually an integer 1 in the database ) the value of new "from_value" field can't be less than old "to_value" that I want to insert (like the graph above) since that would generate a cross between ranges.

I need the verification to prevent the value data from crossing with the old while I am creating a new form

How could I do it via jquery validate plugin? I need to access the database to verify

Thank you very much for reading this far :)

this is my form

my form view

```
<form id="MailMessage-form" method="POST" action="{{route('mail-message.store')}}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="type"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.type')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach ($MailMessageTypes as $value =>$label)
                                            <option value="{{$value}}">{{$label}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="description"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.description')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="description" id="description"
                                              rows="10"> </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="from_value"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.from_value')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input id="from_value" type="number" min="0"
                                           class="form-control @error('from_value') is-invalid @enderror"
                                           name="from_value"
                                           value="{{ old('from_value') }}" required autocomplete="from_value"
                                           autofocus>
                                    @error('from_value')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="to_value"
                                       class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('messages.create.to_value')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input id="to_value" type="number" min="1"
                                           class="form-control @error('to_value') is-invalid @enderror"
                                           name="to_value"
                                           value="{{ old('to_value') }}" required autocomplete="to_value" autofocus>
                                    @error('to_value')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <a href="{{route('mail-message.index')}}"
                                       class="btn btn-white btn-sm">{{__('messages.create.cancel')}}</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                            type="submit">{{__('messages.create.save')}}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

my mailmessagerequest

```
        public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Type' => ['required|integer|max:9'],
        'Description' => ['required|text'],
        'From_Value' => ['required|integer|min:0'],
        'To_Value' => ['required|integer|min:1']
    ];
}
```

thanks for read this :)

Comment: What code have you written so far? What is your exact database schema? Please provide these details so we can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kmoser Is it more understandable now?